# Java How to Convert Token to String?

Tags: java, string, stringtokenizer

Cant seem to figure out how to convert a Token (StringTokenizer) into a String.

I have a String[] of keywords, and I read in multiple lines of text from a text file.
StringTokenizer is used to chop the sentence up,,, at which point I need to pass each Token (the String representation of the Token) to a function for word analysis.

Is there a simple way to extract the string value from the token?

Any help appreciated guys....

Great help guys thanks again!!

Comment: I don't understand, your tokens are already String arent' they?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the method `nextToken()` to return the token as a string

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer("this is a test");
         while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
             wordAnalysis(st.nextToken());//sends string to your function
         }
```

Comment: in the while loop above, I call a function which expects a String.  How do I convert the Token to a String do you know?

Comment: The nextToken method returns a String: see http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html#nextToken().

Answer (score 1):

[`nextToken()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html#nextToken%28%29) called on a StringTokenizer, already returns a `String`.  You don't need to convert that `String` to a `String`.

A Token is just a small (string) portion of a larger String.  Tokens are used in various forms of processing, and a word (the word token) is needed to differentiate the category of items from the specific items.

```
For example, every word, period, and comma in this string is a token.
```

Would lend itself to the following tokens (all of which are strings):

```
For 
example
, 
every 
word
,
period
,
and 
comma 
in 
this 
string 
is 
a 
token
.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i = 0; i<stringArray.length; i++) {
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(stringArray[i]);
    while(st.hasMoreTokens()) {
       callMyProcessingMethod(st.nextToken());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

StringTokenizer is now a legacy class in Java. As of Java 1.4 it is recommended to use the split() method on String which returns a String[].

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)

Comment: Odd, there's nothing in the API to indicate that's it's deprecated (or legacy).  Also split doesn't do the same thing.  Token boundaries are easily identified by "next char" sequences, while REGEX's require a full pattern to match.

Comment: Sorry, it's actually the API doc for StringTokenizer that mentions that it is deprecated.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html